# Show information only after complete form

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (!isset($_COOKIE["loggedin"])){
            ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="POST" name="name_form">
                Username <input type="text" name="username">
                <br/>
                Password <input type="text" name="password">
                <br/>
                Remember Me <input type ="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="1">
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
            </form>
            <?php
                if(preg_match("/<|>/", $_POST["username"])){    
                    echo "do not log in";
                } 
                else if(preg_match("/<|>/", $_POST["password"])){   
                    echo "do not log in";
                }
                else {
                    //Open/create passwords.txt
                    $passwordsFile = fopen("passwords.txt", "a");
                    //write users username and password to passwords.txt
                    $text_written = fwrite($passwordsFile, $_POST["username"] . "," . $_POST["password"] . "\r\n");
                    fclose($passwordsFile);
                    setcookie("loggedin", $_POST["username"]);
                    setcookie("loggedintime", time());
                    echo "<h1>Welcome " . $_COOKIE["loggedin"] . "</h1>";
                    echo "You have been logged in for " . $_COOKIE["loggedintime"] . " seconds.";
                    echo    "<nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Browse books in store</li>
                                    <li>Analytics</li>
                                    <li>Logout</li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>";
                }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

But it's showing the "Welcome ____, you have been logged in for..." part before the user completes the form correctly and I would like to know what to do if I want to show it only after the user complete the form correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: _“But it's showing […] only after the user completes the form correctly and I would like to know what to do if I want to show it only after the user complete the form correctly”_ – so you are asking how to get it to do what it already does …?

Comment: ops, before* hahaha!

Answer (score 1):

Well, step through your code logically.  If the user is not logged in, then this is true:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["loggedin"])){
```

If no form values have been posted, then this is false:

```
if(preg_match("/<|>/", $_POST["username"])){
```

and this is false:

```
else if(preg_match("/<|>/", $_POST["password"])){
```

Thus, the `else` block is executed.  Exactly as designed.

I suspect you want to check if any form post has been received at all.  In which case you could wrap that code in something like:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
```

Which would check if the `submit` button was pressed before evaluating the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are validating form and showing Welcome message without submitting it. Do check below code. It might help you. Validate form after submitting it only.

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["loggedin"])) {
  ?>
      <form action="index.php" method="POST" name="name_form">
          Username <input type="text" name="username">
          <br/>
          Password <input type="text" name="password">
          <br/>
          Remember Me <input type ="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="1">
          <br/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
      </form>
      <?php
      if($_POST) {
        if(preg_match("/<|>/", $_POST["username"])){    
            echo "do not log in";
        } 
        else if(preg_match("/<|>/", $_POST["password"])){   
            echo "do not log in";
        }
        else {
            //Open/create passwords.txt
            $passwordsFile = fopen("passwords.txt", "a");
            //write users username and password to passwords.txt
            $text_written = fwrite($passwordsFile, $_POST["username"] . "," . $_POST["password"] . "\r\n");
            fclose($passwordsFile);
            setcookie("loggedin", $_POST["username"]);
            setcookie("loggedintime", time());
            echo "<h1>Welcome " . $_COOKIE["loggedin"] . "</h1>";
            echo "You have been logged in for " . $_COOKIE["loggedintime"] . " seconds.";
            echo    "<nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Browse books in store</li>
                            <li>Analytics</li>
                            <li>Logout</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>";
        }
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi Gokul,

It solved the problem but now I'm getting this two erros:

Undefined index: loggedin in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment1\index.php on line 42
 
and


Notice: Undefined index: loggedintime in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment1\index.php on line 43.


Besides that, the form continues to appear after the login.

Thank you so much

Comment: I think you are trying to set cookie and using it immediately. Does it has any purpose?